# Results of GeoServer ImageMosaic with Stack Merge

Tags: geoserver, jiffle

I am using GeoServer ImageMosaic to stack multiple geopositioned images (8bit grayscale PNGs) representing measurement data that is fed through a custom Transformation that selects the highest value from each overlapping image in order to produce a "worst-case" overlay that can be served via WMS. When my mosaic only pulls data from a single image, the display looks good.  However, when I have multiple images returned for a given request, I only see the region where all returned data overlaps.

For example, I have the image:

[image]

If this image was near to another similar image, I would have expected to see:

[image]

but instead I only see the overlap, which would be something like:

[image]

At first, I thought it was something within my transformation, but I was able to recreate the issue using a simple Jiffle based transformation of:

```
dest = max(src[1], src[2])
```

It looks like GeoServer has eliminated any non-overlapping portions of the images from the output but I am not sure why. I have experimented with changing the various transparency values in the Layer, but to no effect.

Can anyone explain what is going on with this?

Comment: with out looking at the code I can't be sure but it could be that `max` makes no sense where there is no overlap so it returns nothing (null?)

Comment: Good point. To remove any potential Jiffle issues, I switched back the default "raster" style. I can get the individual values from each band with a GetFeatureInfo call, but the visible portion of the GetMap call is only returning the overlap.

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time looking through the GeoServer, GeoTools, JAI-Ext, and JAI source code.  The heart of the code for ImageMosaic is in the GeoTools project.  The GeoTools code makes use of functions available within the JAI and JAI-Ext to perform much of the image manipulation.  One such operation is the BandMerge operation (https://github.com/geosolutions-it/jai-ext/blob/master/jt-bandmerge/src/main/java/it/geosolutions/jaiext/bandmerge/BandMergeOpImage.java).  This code is written to only operate on the intersection of all the bands.  The following is taken from the layoutHelper function (line 262):

```
    // Cycle on all the images
    for (int i = 0; i < numSources; i++) {
        // Selection of a source
        srci = (RenderedImage) sources.get(i);
        // Intersection of the initial bounds with the source bounds
        destBounds = destBounds.intersection(new Rectangle(srci.getMinX(), srci.getMinY(), srci
                .getWidth(), srci.getHeight()));

        ...

    }
```

Therefore there is nothing that can be done to expand the image from a GeoServer perspective.

Comment: Nothing you can do as a user... but as a developer, one could extend the images to the union of footprints (with zeroes, nodata, something) and then do the bandmerge. Projects are open to Pull Requests, contact the dev lists about it.